# What species is the Borg Queen?

Tags: star-trek

We've seen several examples of their Queen and she always appears to be of the same species. What species is that?

[image]

Comment: It looks like this has already been addressed here http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4912/who-are-species-125 Would still like to get a species name if one could be found though

Answer (score 6):

In VOY: "[Dark Frontier](http://www.chakoteya.net/Voyager/517.htm)", the Borg Queen states that she comes from [Species 125](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Species_125), a species that is presumably (given their low numbered designation) one of the earliest species assimilated by the Borg and possibly now extinct:

> **QUEEN:** *We all originated from lesser species. I myself came from species one two five, but that's irrelevant now. We are Borg.*

The (non-canon) Computer game "[Star Trek : Legacy](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_Legacy)" suggests that the Borg favour this species because "*the females...displayed a mental prowess enabling them to sift through thousands of thoughts and bring order to chaos*"

Comment: Interesting. Is species 125 known by any name other than the Borg designation? Species 5618: Human, Species 3259: Vulcan, etc.

Comment: @morgan - Nope, not that I'm aware of.

Comment: I prefer the **Star Trek Manga** origin - [Side Effects](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Shinsei_Shinsei)... it's rather _badass_