# What species is Hugh?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, borg

What species is the Borg [Hugh](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Hugh)?

(Slightly related: [What species is the Borg Queen?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/58867/what-species-is-the-borg-queen))

Answer (score 6):

Hugh, introduced before the concept of species numbers was first used, was never described/explained as to which species he came from, in either canon or extended material. Hugh is simply a Borg Drone.

Comment: I agree with this.  Certainly, there is no canon information on Hugh's origins.  There are non-canon novels involving Hugh, but they also don't state the race or planet that he comes from. +1

Answer (score 5):

Within the main canon (TV/Films) Hugh's species is never revealed.

That being said, we get a little more info about Hugh in the EU novel "[Greater than the Sum](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Greater_Than_the_Sum)". Hugh seems to be a [Heinz](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=heinz%2057), incubated by the Borg and artificially generated using **the genetic material from *multiple* species;**

> Hugh had already told the new crew members how Geordi had shown him
>   individuality and how Picard had sent him back to “infect” his fellow
>   drones with that sense of self. He had told how his cube full of
>   incubated drones, with no prior identity or social structure to fall
>   back on

and

> “Of course,” Beverly said, nodding. “Your people were incubated
>   drones-essentially androgynous.”
>
> “And the Zeros,” Grabowski said, “well, most of us had our
>   reproductive machinery torn out of us and replaced with circuitry, **our
>   gametes harvested to be engineered into new incubated drones.** Those
>   few of us who retained the organs had our hormones and nervous systems
>   messed with so much that we’re…no longer capable of sexual response.”